# Unable to scroll due to error pop-up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set the error to edit text, now my problem is whenever I click on error icon a pop-up with error message appears. If that pop-up is available I am unable to scroll.
So my requirement is to close error pop-up alone on scroll, please provide all your solution

Answer (score 0):

when you are scrolling then clear all edit text and 'setError(null)' for all edit text.

Comment: But I need error icon setting it null will remove error icon.only while scrolling if any error pop-up open just want to dismiss it so that I can scroll

Answer (score 0):

@ RAVI try to this code hope this can help you..

```
 window.setTouchable(true);
window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
window.setFocusable(false);
```

and in scoll listener..

```
 listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        float height;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            float height = event.getY();
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                this.height = height;
            }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(this.height < height){    
                    window.dismiss();    
                    Log.v(TAG, "Scrolled up");
                }else if(this.height > height){
                     window.dismiss();
                    Log.v(TAG, "Scrolled down");
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is Window here, how to get it if doing in scroll change()

Comment: Here window means your open window.